# How to [semi] authenticate a user without session/cookie/sign in?

Tags: php, sql, security

(I'm sure I'm not the first person with this issue, but I wasn't able to find much via Google/Stack Overflow. Apologies in advance if it's a duplicate.)

My site can be used as a data source for the program Mp3tag: it accesses a page on my site, scrapes data, and uses it to tag mp3 files. I want "vip" members of my site to have access to higher-resolution artwork.

Unfortunately, Mp3tag acts like a fresh browser each time: there's no cookie/session data, and the program can't display any sort of "sign in" prompt. So my issue is that **I need to [semi-]securely authenticate a user without having them sign in**.

My plan is to store a simple md5 hash for each vip member, have Mp3tag include the username/hash in the url it uses to access my site, and then have the server authenticate this. (For the record, I'm using PHP/SQL.)

(*Note: I don't need this to be super secure.* I won't be using the hash for any kind of sign in or access to anything else on the site. The worst case scenario *should* be that someone manages to guess a vip member's hash, and then has access to high-res artwork―if that's the worst case, I'm ok with that.)

But **will this simple hash cause security issues elsewhere?** All passwords are hashed/salted, use PHP's password functions, etc., so having a separate md5 hash (that's unrelated to password) shouldn't cause any issues, right?

And secondly, **is there a more secure way to do this?** I guess I could add some sort of IP address checks, but that's the only other idea I had.

Comment: How does Mp3tag know the username/hash? The user has to type it into a config screen somewhere?

Comment: Mp3tag can run custom scripts, which essentially say "access this url, then scrape the first line from it and treat that as album title" etc. So in that script, I'll set the url to blah.com?album=whatever&username=user&hash=xxx. Each user will have to edit the script to use their username and hash.

Answer (score 1):

> But will this simple hash cause security issues elsewhere?

No.

> All
>   passwords are hashed/salted, use PHP's password functions, etc., so
>   having a separate md5 hash (that's unrelated to password) shouldn't
>   cause any issues, right?

Right. This is a simple "something you have" authentication. It's basically a key that's relatively easy to copy. Not the strongest mechanism, but you're only protecting an image, so it doesn't have to be. As long as your actual account authentication uses separate credentials, you're not weakening that.

> And secondly, is there a more secure way to do this? I guess I could
>   add some sort of IP address checks, but that's the only other idea I
>   had.

IP-based access can be very effective, but tends to be a real pain when your clients move around. It's probably not worth it for this level of protection.

You might use a stronger hash, but that's irrelevant if the page isn't served over HTTPS.

I think your idea is fine, just use `random_bytes()` as the source, not something predictable like the username. Think of it as just a second password that they don't get to make up.

Comment: Can't upvote yet, but thank you! Good reminder to use random_bytes().